# URL based on the current directory in PHP

Tags: php, url

Let's say I have three php pages namely `Header.php`, `Footer.php` and `LeftSideBar.php` in the following directory

```
C:\wamp\www\zoomin\header_footer_sidebar
```

and usual php pages in the following directory.

```
C:\wamp\www\zoomin\www.zoomin.com
```

I can include those three pages as follows.

```
<?php       
    require_once("../header_footer_sidebar/Header.php");
    require_once("../header_footer_sidebar/LeftSideBar.php");
    require_once("../header_footer_sidebar/Footer.php");
?>
```

This can work fine but when I need to keep pages in other directories like the following,

```
C:\wamp\www\zoomin\www.zoomin.com\directoryA\directoryB\directoryC
```

I need to copy those three pages into an appropriate directory because `Header.php`, `Footer.php` and `LeftSideBar.php` **may contain some urls** at least some image urls of some other directory which would not work with the preceding url.

I want to keep `Header.php`, `Footer.php` and `LeftSideBar.php` only in the following directory as mentioned above.

```
C:\wamp\www\zoomin\header_footer_sidebar
```

regardless of in which directory I save my web pages. The following approach would not work in this case.

```
$protocol."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

or

```
$protocol."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

Is there a  way to suit this requirement?

Comment: php_self is bad. also use SERVER_NAME instead of HTTP_HOST. requiring those three files on every php page is not DRY.

Comment: could you use relative links to whatever the current directory is in your .php files?  is this for CLI, or could you explain a little more why REQUEST_URI couldn't be parsed to determine the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your [`include_path`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) in php.ini.

Comment: It's showing `;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"` but my requirement is that those three php files `Header.php`, `Footer.php` and `LeftSideBar.php` have some urls (like image urls `<img src="url">`). I want to use only those files in my entire application regardless of the direcory in which I'm saving **other** php files. What happens is that when I save php files in a complex directory structure, the image urls in those files need to be modified and to avoid this, I need to copy those three files in an appropriate folder which I don't want. Is this possible?

Comment: Your requirement still isn't clear.  Do the three files need to be accessible via their URL?  If so, they need to be placed somewhere within your DocumentRoot or via an Alias.  Do they need to refer to <img> sources?  Have them find their images using non-relative URLS, i.e. `src="/img/logo.png"`.  Remember that resources are served according to the directory structure under your DocumentRoot, regardless of the locations of the files.  Think of each embedded resource as a distinct query, unrelated to the parent that included it.